# First science fiction movie or tv show that had a complete language created for it?

Tags: movie, history-of, languages

I read a question about what the language used in 1951's The Day the Earth Stood Still was based upon and I guessed, apparently rightly, that it was just made up. I also of course know that there is a Klingon-English dictionary for the language spoken in Star Trek flicks (I do not think STOS had any linguist-created language). So was one of the Star Trek flicks the first movie to bother with creating a "real" artificial language? Did anyone try, even short of a full vocabulary but maybe basic, 300 or 800 words of a language prior to Star Trek?

EDIT: I want to motivate the question. I am amazed that some movie or tv producer would go through the expense but I actually think it is worth it -- this is a detail that even a non-linguist can hear in a "real" language vs gibberish. I have not looked up star wars but my money is on a linguist having been involved.

Comment: You ask about TV and movies only, there was a 1950's radio adaptation of Lord of the Rings - for the books of which Tolkien created/enhanced Quenya.....

Comment: No TV show has had a *complete* language created for it. Even languages like Klingon and Tengwar/Quenya are, at best, partial.

Comment: @valorum: i mention basic: limited words but real grammar. with 300-800 words of a language you can survive. maybe i should have specified created by a linguist.

Comment: @Alith: if they added to the language specifically for the radio show that would be interesting but if they just used what JRRT had already created that would not be what I am looking for.

Comment: All the languages in Star Wars are total gibberish. They typically just use words that sound a bit like the word they're aping; e.g. Slamo = slimeball. Latterly they've tried to add some structure.

Comment: @Valorum: they did go through the trouble to create an alphabet, i read. The gibberish i heard sounds a lot more language like than, for example, speaking in tongues which is truly gibberish.

Comment: [_The Fifth Element_](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119116/trivia?ref_=tt_trv_trv) includes the "Divine Language", which was worked out in enough detail (400 words) that actors could chat in it. But this dates back only to 1997.

Comment: @InvisibleTrihedron: still interesting, seems like star trek may have been a trail blazer.

Comment: @Valorum Maybe not _all_ the languages in Star Wars are gibberish. Apparently _The Return of the Jedi_ includes a [terrestrial language](https://www.csmonitor.com/1983/0728/072823.html).

Comment: Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructed_language#Artistic_languages

Comment: Not worthy of an answer: [Futurama](https://www.thetvdb.com/series/futurama) had, if not a language, then at least its own [written](https://theinfosphere.org/Alien_languages) "alien language".

Comment: Highly related: [Was Tolkien the first to invent languages purely for fictional works?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/77330/31394) (cc @Alith) Not a duplicate though, since this question is purely about screen works.

Comment: @Valorum maybe the original Klingon, but the version since The Search for Spock ('84) is 'complete' enough that works from Sun Tzu and Shakespeare (Hamlet, Much Ado About Nothing), plus texts such as The Epic of Gilgamesh and the Tao Te Ching have been translated into Klingon.

Comment: While the works of Tolkien predates any of the other apparent candidates, would it not be excluded from consideration as being fantasy and not science fiction (ditto Game of Thrones)? Seems the closest candidate is Klingon, even if never made complete for the needs of any Star Trek movie or TV show scripts.

Comment: @AnthonyX: no, i don't think Tolkien should be excluded since fantasy vs scifi is not always clear. however, i think languages made up for books is different than for movies or tv and that is why i asked specifically about that kind of media. i suspect people have been making up languages for centuries and sometimes withing the framework of fiction.

Comment: @Noughtnaut apparently Futurama's alien language(s) are merely a cipher: https://theinfosphere.org/Alien_languages

Answer (score 24):

I'll propose Pakuni from 1974 Land of the Lost series.   Since they were primitive apemen - a 300 word language on a technicality has the best chance of being "complete".
See http://lotl.popapostle.com/html/pakuni.htm

Though obviously Star Trek III's Klingon dictionary and Tolkien's elf languages are more notable in other ways.

Answer (score 15):

[Ubbi Dubbi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubbi_dubbi) was created in 1972 for the PBS children's show *Zoom*.

Because it is derived from English, it is a matter of opinion whether it counts for this question (i.e. what constitutes "creating" a language).  On one hand, it is not completely artificial like Klingon or Tolkien languages.  On the other hand, Ubbi Dubbi is as "complete" as English, unlike the other languages.

Comment: And DrSheldon was not happy when Amy and Penny used it as their secret language.

Comment: I remember learning that! It was a blast confusing friends and foes alike.

Comment: I would argue that this isn't really a new language, it's just English spoken with a speech impediment.

Comment: I was going to suggest Pig Latin, which appears in films as early as 1913, but it apparently wasn't created expressly for film/TV and it is very doubtful that anyone would agree that it is a complete language; Wikipedia calls it an argot rather than a language.

Comment: This may arguably fit the letter of the question, but it doesn’t seem to fit the spirit of the question at all — it’s nothing to do with the creative detail of developing an actual new language.

Answer (score 7):

**Probably the 1974 children’s TV series *Land of the Lost*, with the language *Pakuni*, created by UCLA linguist Victoria Fromkin.**

I take the question as asking about languages developed beyond isolated words or language games, into at least a rudimentary *conlang* (constructed language).  Wikipedia has a handy [list of conlangs in fiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_constructed_languages#Languages_used_in_fiction).  Digging into their examples, the earliest ones in film and television are:

- 1974: Pakuni, *Land of the Lost*, created by Victoria Fromkin
- 1982: Vulcan, Star Trek (isolated words appeared from 1966; first developed into a rudimentary conlang in 1982 for *The Wrath of Khan*, by Marc Okrand)
- 1985: Klingon, Star Trek (isolated words appeared from 1979; developed into a basic conlang for *The Search for Spock*, again by Marc Okrand)

So Pakuni appears to be the first of these to be developed into a systematic, if rudimentary, conlang.  Frath Wiki, a conlang wiki, [supports the belief that this was the earliest](https://www.frathwiki.com/Pakuni):

> Pakuni is of interest to the conlanging community primarily as a matter of historical fact. Later inventions, such as Klingon and Na'vi, are certainly more well known. […] Okrand [for *Star Trek*] and Frommer [for *Avatar*] and Peterson [*Game of Thrones*] have raised the bar immensely […] It is simply the case that Fromkin [creator of *Pakuni*] was showing them how to do it, way back in the 1970s.

There is a longer history of fictional conlangs in literature. Tolkien is widely credited for their first use, with the languages of *Lord of the Rings* (published 1954); [this previous sff.se answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/77330/was-tolkien-the-first-to-invent-languages-purely-for-fictional-works) discusses and supports that claim.  His languages of Middle-Earth were far more developed than the above early film/TV examples were when introduced.

(Note: Pakuni has already been named in [@lucasbachmann’s answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/239514/475), but I wanted to add some information and context to back up the claim that it’s the first.)

Comment: I remember being astonished when I learned that the widely respected linguist Victoria Fromkin was also a conlanger.

Comment: @einpoklum: Absolutely, and I acknowledged that in my answer.  I wanted to give some extra information and context, which I think is helpful for assessing how well Pakuni fits the question’s intent, and how likely it is to be the earliest such (and is also just interesting).  I originally considered adding it as a comment on lucasbachmann’s answer, but it was much too long for a comment so I wrote as a new answer.  So while the candidate conlang is the same, I think most of the substance of my answer adds value and doesn’t duplicate lucasbachmann’s?

Comment: I upvoted you thanks for your efforts